# How do you check for a background image in nightwatch?

Tags: nightwatch.js

How do you check for a background image in nightwatch? How do you make sure a background image is correctly loaded? Background image is loaded using css.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

```
browser.waitForElementVisible('.someSelector', 15000)

browser.expect.element('.someSelector').to.have.css('background-image').which.equals('url("https://www.someimage.com/image1.png")');
```

Comment: Doesn't that just check that the correct css has been applied? Not that the actual image has loaded and is visible